# Filling a infinite colored graph with basis

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, physics, coloring

This is a mathematical question raised from engineering and physics:

Is there some established mathematical approach in filling a physical lattice with some colored basis (black and white here)? For example, a triangular lattice can be filled with 
[image: basis] to get[image: filling]

While [image] alone cannot give any filled colored graph. Is there any general systematic mathematical approach in solving this problem?

Comment: Is it allowed to rotate a basis element in using it to build the pattern?

Comment: Yes. You can perform symmtey operations on the basis.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://mathoverflow.net/q/147374/12357

Comment: @user40780, please do not simultaneously cross-post the same question across different StackExchange sites.  This is frowned upon because it leads to duplication of effort.

Comment: Also cross-posted at http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83855